# torrc startup scripts - a -f /full/path/to/your/fully/custom/config?

Tags: configuration, debian

This is related to [Is there a way in tor to tell to prefer tor relays from another country?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/is-there-a-way-in-tor-to-tell-to-prefer-tor-relays-from-another-country/15924?noredirect=1#comment17993_15924) where somebody named [Alexey Vesnin](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/9291/alexey-vesnin) shared something about sharing the full path in your startup scripts, see [Is there a way in tor to tell to prefer tor relays from another country?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/is-there-a-way-in-tor-to-tell-to-prefer-tor-relays-from-another-country/15924?noredirect=1#comment17990_15924) but I'm confused/haven't really understood what he means by that.

Could anybody elaborate ?

Also I'm unaware what the switches `-a`  and `-f` are supposed to denote on the shell.

Looking forward to know.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and good time of day! the `-f` key for tor binary is a key that makes tor use the specifically located config, not the config from location it considers to be a default one(this folder path can be specified when tor is compiled). a very simple explaination is that *regardless* of the default paths and, pehaps, configs installed with tor, you're explicitly telling Tor what you want. In example, you have in `/etc` folder a file named `torconfig.cfg` for your custom settings, so the tor execution line will be `tor -f /etc/torconfig.cfg`. Why not just `tor -f torconfig.cfg`? Because it will look for the file `torconfig.cfg` in the *current folder* that can be quite different depending on how and where from tor is executed, and when you're writing path starting with a leading slash - it makes it clear and pointing to the exact specific file *regardless* of where from and how the tor is executed. a good howto about relative and absolute paths can be found [here](https://www.linux.com/blog/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix)